# How to use a function of a struct in another struct?

Tags: c, struct

i'm doing a simple project in C in which, for the moment, i use two structs: Player and Card. 
I have created the 2 struct in different header files, because functions in Player use Card, but also other elements that I haven't already done.
When I try to use getId() in Player, the VSCode's compiler says:

> reference to external symbol _getId not resolved in _discardCard()

card.h code is:

```
#include <stdbool.h> 
typedef struct card{
    int id;
    bool black;
    int numElems;
    char* text[3];
}card;

card* initCard(int id,bool black,char* text[],int numElems)
int getId(card* c);
```

card.c code is:

```
#include "carta.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

...
int getId(carta* c){
    return c->id;
}
```

Instead the code for Player.h is:

```
#include "card.h"
#define CARDSMAX 5

typedef struct{
    bool master;
    int id;
    int points;
    char* nickname;
    card* cards[CARDSMAX];
    int NumCards;
}player;

... //other functions

card* discardCard(int id,player* g);
```

The code for Player.c is:

```
#include "player.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
player* initPlayer(char* nickname,int id){
    player* g=(player*) malloc(sizeof (player));
    g->id=id;
    g->nickname=nickname;
    g->master=false;
    g->points=0;
    g->NumCards=0;
    for(int i=0;i<CARDSMAX;i++){
        g->cards[i]=(card*)malloc(sizeof(card));
    }
    return g;
}

....   

card* DiscardCard(int id,player* g){
    for(int i=0;i<CARDSMAX;i++){
        card* c=g->cards[i];
        if(getId(c)==id){
            card* e= g->cards[i];
            g->cards[i]=NULL;
            g->NumCards--;
            return e;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Can someone help me? (If you see some inconsistency in the code, it'is because i tried a fast translation from my language)

Comment: Spelling? `GetId` vs `getId`. The linker says the first, your prototype says the second.

Comment: Typo corrected: or is it still there in `card.c`? What did you use to compile? Was the object file from `card.c` specified for linking?

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry, I had typed the wrong thing, the compiler says getId and discardCard, i replcaced the message with the correct one

Comment: To compile i'm using window's compiler (cl player.c)

Comment: Well does your MAKEFILE tell it to compile `card.c` and link `card.obj`? How does it know anthying about `card.c`? It knows about `card.h` but where do you tell it about `card.c`?

Comment: In which .c file is the implementation of `getId`? I don't see it in the code you posted.

Comment: I don't use a MAKEFILE, I have thinked that it could be enough to include card.h. So is it necessary to use a makefile?

Comment: `card.h` could be anything. There is no rule that says it has anything to do with, or there must also be, a file called `card.c`. It don't use `CL` I use `NMAKE` which needs a MAKEFILE. I don't know the syntax for `CL` sorry.

Comment: Please see [Compiler Command-Line Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-command-line-syntax?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Whether you use a makefile or not, the main thing is you need an implementation for `getId`, compiled to object code, and you have to link to it.

Comment: Ok, I found the way to link cart.obj, i first compiled card.c and then player.c with: `cl player.c /link card.obj` and finally everything works, thank you so much @WeatherVane and @Dmitri

Comment: Please make yourself an answer describing the solution you found. That makes a nice, somewhat useful Q/A pair, which is the goal of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

So, as suggested , the problem was that in Windows' compiler, when you use struct that use function defined in other structs,it is required to pass the .obj file during the compilation .
For doing this you need to compile every .c file that is used by others singulary and then link the .obj file created in this fase. 
So in my case the first step is to compile:

```
cl card.c
```

that create a card.obj (the Windows' compiler could show you a message that says something like:"The start point is not indicated" if you don't use a main in this first file, don't worry and carry on with this procedure) and then I compile:

```
cl player.c /link card.obj
```

So in this way you pass the compiled object in which it's provided the implementation of all the function in the struct.